# Calculate object position in 3D from photo

Tags: c++, opencv, three.js, computer-vision

I am working on sort of AR where, through OpenCV in a C++ algorithm, I find an image marker. After that, in JS (Three.js), I want to project on this position some 3D object.

This 2D image tracking works fine. The output is 4 pretty precise 2D points in perspective calculated from key point homography.

But I am lost, when I want to calculate the 3D position of these corners in space. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

So after some research I (re)discovered function `solvePnP` in OpenCV.

Reason why I didn't want to use it first time was, because I though, that I can use it only for 3D objects. Not 2D. But solution was, just add 0 Z position to 3D object coordinates.

In Python like this:

```
object_points = np.array([
    (-target_image_height / 2, -target_image_width / 2, 0),
    (-target_image_height / 2, target_image_width / 2, 0),
    (target_image_height / 2, target_image_width / 2, 0),
    (target_image_height / 2, -target_image_width / 2, 0),
], dtype=np.float32)
```

After that just add corresponding 2D coordinates:

```
corners = np.array([
    [ 643.63635, 1113.8246 ],
    [ 1290.5548, 1073.5529 ],
    [ 1223.0352, 2609.2234 ],
    [ 624.71985, 2441.5803 ],
])
```

and call `solvePnP`:

```
retval, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(object_points, corners, np.array(calibration_data['mtx']), np.array(calibration_data['dist']))
```

**Note:** Camera calibration matrix make huge difference in result. So you need to calibrate it through chessboard or similar methods.

Output is rotation and translation vector of camera.